# Sympy Broadcasting Matrix-Vector Addition for MLP

Tags: matrix, vector, sympy, array-broadcasting, mlp

I'm trying to get a grasp on declarative programming, so I've started learning Sympy and my "hello world" is to try to represent a standard MLP by converting a vanilla numpy implementation I found online. I am getting stuck trying to add the bias vector. Is there a differentiable way to do this operation in Sympy?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import random
import sympy as sp

i   = 3
o   = 1
x   = sp.Symbol('x')
w   = sp.Symbol('w')
b   = sp.Symbol('b')
y   = sp.Symbol('y')
Φ   = sp.tanh # activation function
mlp = Φ(x*w+b)
L   = lambda a, e: a - e # loss function
C   = L(mlp, y)
dC  = sp.diff(C, w) # partial deriv of C with respect to each weight
η   = 0.01               # learning rate
if __name__ == "__main__":
    random.seed(1)
    train_inputs  = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
    train_outputs = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T
    W  = 2 * np.random.rand(i, o) - 1 # TODO parameterize initialization
    W  = sp.Matrix(W)
    B  = 2 * np.random.rand(1, o) - 1 # TODO parameterize initialization
    B  = sp.Matrix(B)
    for temp, ye in zip(train_inputs, train_outputs):
        X  = sp.Matrix(temp)
        ya = mlp.subs({'x':X, 'w':W, 'b':B}).n()
        Δ  = dC.subs({'y':ye, 'x':X, 'b':B, 'w':W}).n()
        W -= η * Δ
        b -= η * Δ
```

Comment: MLP - machine learning?  I haven't explored the `sympy.Matrix` stuff much, but I don't think it has the multidimensional power of `numpy`.  It does not implement `broadcasting`.   `sympy` is for doing symbolic math, basic algebra and beyond.  I don't recommend trying to reinvent numeric tools in `sympy`.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do here. The code as shown does not work because of missing imports and symbol declarations.

Comment: @hpaulj I think I need to create a symbol for broadcasting or at least matrix-vector addition. Mainly I'm exploring sympy's potential. For example, what will happen if I call simplify() on a trained deep network (probably not much)?
I'm curious to try varying all the parameters to the MLP (such as activation, aggregation and conjunction operators), training on various problems and seeing if any of the models are 'similar.'
I wonder if it will yield insights into incrementally building a hybrid system (ie with MLP, SVM, etc.).
Maybe a declarative sympy/codegen/numpy AI API is worthwhile...

Comment: sympy doesn't support broadcasting and only can be combined with numpy in very limited situations

Comment: If you use MatrixSymbol for b, x and w then you can do this as something like `(b[0, 0] * OneMatrix(3, 1) + HadamardProduct(x, w)).applyfunc(tanh)`.